# Select menu arrow style for Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, css, select

Here is the style used to use a custom arrow for the select list but it is not working in IE and Mozilla Firefox.
Are there any hacks/solutions for this?

```
select{
    -webkit-appearance:none; -moz-appearance:none !important;
    border-radius:4px ; border:#cccccc solid 1px ;
    height:26px; width:210px; padding-left:8px;
    font:normal 14px Myriad Pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#7f7f7f;
    background-image:url(../images/list_arrow.jpg); background-position:185px;  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a pure CSS solution for IE, but something you could do for Firefox would be to cover the arrow of the `select` (just the arrow!) with another element for which the background is your custom arrow and use `pointer-events: none` on that element (this also works for Chrome and Safari).

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3414966)

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>item 1</option>
    <option>item 2</option>
    <option>item 3</option>
</select>
<div class='arrow'></div>
```

CSS:

```
select, .arrow { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
option { padding: 0 1em; }
.arrow {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin-left: -28px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(arrow.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

For IE, you could also cover the arrow of the select, add a click listener on the element covering the arrow and open the select when the arrow is clicked. This would actually work for any browser, but it involves JavaScript.

Comment: but you cant click on the arrow in ie :(

Comment: I've said in the answer that this method works only for Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: thn I cant use it. thnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-o-appearance: none;
```

you should use this whole code for all the browsers...webkit only supports chrome and safari...moz is for firefox....

or you could user "pointer-events:none" for a div over a  select box but this doesn't work in IE...